# run ionic framework into docker does not create localy folder/files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, docker, ionic2

I am new to docker and I am trying to create a container for build a nodejs and ionic instance.

In my project folder named **DockerEnv**, I have created a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml`.

This is my **Dockerfile** content:

```
FROM node:6.9.4

# install cordova >=4.2.0 for ionic framework 2
RUN npm install -g cordova@4.2.0

# install ionic 2 framework
RUN npm install -g ionic@2.2.1

ENV HOME=/src

RUN mkdir $HOME

RUN cd $HOME

# create an ionic project as seen on the doc here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/tutorial/
RUN ionic start ionic-app --v2

ENV IONIC=/ionic-app

WORKDIR $HOME/$IONIC

RUN cd $HOME/$IONIC

EXPOSE 8100
EXPOSE 35729

CMD ionic serve
```

And this is my **docker-compose.yml** content:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ionic_web_app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./src:/app"
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
      - "35729:35729"
```

Every step are running well except at the end I have this error when I launch the command `docker-compose up --build`

> Successfully built fe047d159309
>
> Recreating 40b083681f07_40b083681f07_ionicdockerenv_ionic_web_app_1
>
> Attaching to dockerenv_ionic_web_app_1
>
> ionic_web_app_1  | Couldn't find ionic.config.json file. Are you in an
>   Ionic project?
>
> dockerenv_ionic_web_app_1 exited with code 1

And in fact, I have well my folder /src in my project folder but no
ionic project was created in !

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Run this to connect to the instance you have created. `docker exec -it dockerenv_ionic_web_app_1 bash`. Then try to find the source code there. Also, why do you create the /src, won't `ionic-start` create it what you will need?

Comment: @ipinak by doing `docker exec -it dockerenv_ionic_web_app_1 bash`, I run the `ls` command in order to see wich files there are and I can see all the ionic 2 structure (folder and files), but by doing `ionic start` not create the ionic structure locally in my current project folder i-e `DockerEnv`. I think this problem comes from my `docker-compose.yml` file (volume instruction maybe).

Comment: Can you tell me what the structure of the directories when you ls? It would be useful to see what the /src contains as well.

Comment: @ipinak following rainkiz answer, I edit my dockerfile. The app is launched very weel, but I have no local files from ionic in my project direct directory. The src/ folder contain an empty folder. If I lauch the docker bash with the command you suggest me, I can see all the ionic files and folder, but there are not present in my local project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your problem is you're changing into the wrong directory to start the app. Maybe try this (note that I've made sure the directory you created when initializing the app is the dir you use as your working dir). So I'm explicitly creating the app in:

`$HOME/$IONIC_APP`

```
FROM node:6.9.4

# install cordova >=4.2.0 for ionic framework 2
RUN npm install -g cordova@4.2.0

# install ionic 2 framework
RUN npm install -g ionic@2.2.1

ENV HOME=/src

RUN mkdir $HOME

ENV IONIC_APP=ionic-app

RUN cd $HOME

# create an ionic project as seen on the doc here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/tutorial/
RUN ionic start $HOME/$IONIC_APP --v2

WORKDIR $HOME/$IONIC_APP

EXPOSE 8100
EXPOSE 35729

CMD ionic serve
```

Comment: it works except it is not create ionic 2 files locally, but my docker container launch ionic 2 framework. Maybe my docker-compose.yml is not correctly write (under volumes instance I think). See my comment under my initial post.